# What is the area of trapezoid DBCE?

Tags: geometry, triangles

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REszJ.png)

[image]
I'm preparing for the upcoming AMC 10 competition, and I've stumbled across this problem while completing practice tests. This is the only question that has given me such great difficulty.  I cannot find a way to get to the solution; I must be missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

(Question linked above)

Comment: Hint: Subdivide the large upper triangle into those area-$1$ triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a few more small triangles:

[image: Updated Problem 9]

Now you can see $16$ small congruent triangles of area $1$. The remaining area (of the trapezoid $DBCE$) is $40-16\cdot 1=24$. The answer $E$ is right.

Comment: You are lucky that the little triangles under $A$ actually fit. In general, that does not have to be the case

Comment: @imranfat While I think it is unnecessary to actually draw the triangles, given that the segment $DE$ is exactly partitioned into the bases of an integer number of triangles, it _does_ have to be the case that the little triangles under $A$ will fit.

Comment: @imranfat this is not luck. Due to having parallel sides, all the four small triangles oriented the same as the big ones are similar to the big one, and having the same area, they are congruent to each other. The three 'upside down' small triangles are also congruent to them, having two sides and an angle equal. Thus their three bases are exactly the same as the four bases of the previous four triangles: they add up to $\frac{3}{4}DE$, and then you can obviously fit exactly three triangles "right way up". Then you proceed with two triangles "upside down" etc.

Answer (score 1):

If proportion between areas of two similar triangle is $p$, then proportion of corresponding sides is $\sqrt{p}$. By using this fact, we can say if $|DF| = |FG| = |GH| = |HE| = k$, then we have $|BC| = 2k\sqrt{10}$ (comes from $\sqrt{40}$). Then by using the similarity of the triangles $\Delta ADE$ and $\Delta ABC$, we have

$$\bigg(\frac{|DE|}{|BC|}\bigg)^2 = \frac{A(ADE)}{A(ABC)} \implies \frac{4}{10} = \frac{A(ADE)}{A(ABC)}$$ where $A(ABC) = 40$ is given. Therefore, $A(ADE) = 16$ and hence $A(DBCE) = A(ABC)-A(ADE) = 40-16 = 24$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Consider the lengths 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x}{y} =\frac{3}{4}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Consider the are areas 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x^2}{y^2} =\frac{9}{16}=\frac{A}{A+7}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Linear algebra rapidly gives $A=9$, hence the trapezoid is $40-9-7$.

Comment: I find this very compelling...+1

Answer (score 0):

In the figure below, the vertices of one of the "smallest" triangles
are labeled $D,$ $F,$ and $G.$

[image]

Triangle $\triangle ADE$ is similar to triangle $\triangle DFG,$
and side $DE$ of $\triangle ADE$ is exactly $4$ times as long
as the corresponding side $DF$ of $\triangle DFG.$
Denoting the areas of the triangles by
$\mathit{Area}(\triangle ADE)$ and $\mathit{Area}(\triangle DFG),$
and using the fact that the areas of similar polygons are proportional
to the squares of corresponding sides,
$$\mathit{Area}(\triangle ADE) = 
\left(\frac{DE}{DF}\right)^2 \mathit{Area}(\triangle DFG)
 = 4^2 \cdot 1 = 16.$$

Since triangle $ABC$ is partitioned by $DE$ into triangle
$\triangle ADE$ and trapezoid $DBCE,$
$$\mathit{Area}(\triangle ABC) =
  \mathit{Area}(\triangle ADE) + \mathit{Area}(DBCE)$$
and therefore
$$\mathit{Area}(DBCE) =
   \mathit{Area}(\triangle ABC) - \mathit{Area}(\triangle ADE)
   = 40 - 16 = 24.$$